# WinJS - Preventing two quick button presses

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, double-click

We have a situation in an application in WinJS where our serialised data is read from a file on disk, and depending on the page, different sections of the file are accessed.

The problem we have is that when a user double taps a control, button, listview etc, the system will try to read the file twice and sporadically blows up.

Is there a recommended route in WinJS to prevent or handle double presses on controls? other than something like manually disabling and re-enabling all buttons when pressed?

We've looked at some options, including overriding addEventListener, but none are perfect, any suggestions in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Additional: Whilst in this example the problem is reading a file, we have other applications where performing quick double presses on lists will try to navigate to a page twice (and add it to the nav.history twice), so it seems like there are a number of places and symptoms where this kind of thing could occur.

Comment: Could you have a variable which is set on each press such as "ProcessingValue" that all buttons check before continuing?

Comment: Hi Nate, this is one of the suggestions we're looking out, downside is that this could be triggered in so many areas of the application that we'd need to write the same code many times, or look at some way of overriding addEventListener and making all the underlying listener functions return promises so we could set the 'processingvalue' back after they are done.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to disable the buttons while processing and reenable them when done. This will provide appropriate feedback to the user if things take longer than expected.

You could disable them via databinding rather than setting them all manually.

HTML

```
<button id="button1" data-win-bind="disabled: disabled">Click</button>
<button id="button2" data-win-bind="disabled: disabled">Click</button>
<button id="button3" data-win-bind="disabled: disabled">Click</button>
<button id="button4" data-win-bind="disabled: disabled">Click</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var bindingSource;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());

        var disabledContext = { disabled: false }

        var btn = document.getElementById("button1");
        btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
        WinJS.Binding.processAll(btn, disabledContext);

        btn = document.getElementById("button2");
        btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
        WinJS.Binding.processAll(btn, disabledContext);

        btn = document.getElementById("button3");
        btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
        WinJS.Binding.processAll(btn, disabledContext);

        btn = document.getElementById("button4");
        btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
        WinJS.Binding.processAll(btn, disabledContext);

        bindingSource = WinJS.Binding.as(disabledContext);
    }
};

function buttonClickHandler(eventInfo) {
    bindingSource.disabled = true

    WinJS.Promise.timeout(5000).then(function (c) {
        bindingSource.disabled = false
    });
}
```

--Rob

Comment: Hi Rob, not a bad idea except that we're pretty much needing to implement this on any press, buttons, lists, hyperlinks etc. which all have slightly different 'disabled' behaviours we'd need to implement. 
Also, we the suggestion for a 5 sec timeout on the button press would 'probably' work, except that it seems that we'd not have an effective way of knowing when our 'work' on the button was done unless every handler we used returned a promise, whilst some do, many don't and it'd be fairly major work to change them all to work in this way.

Comment: The 5 second timeout is a placeholder for whatever work your app needs to do. You wouldn't want that in a real app. Most controls will bind to disabled in the same way, and you can include other properties in your binding source and write a function which can set them all to disable / enable. If you don't have a way to know when the work is done then any method to prevent double access while the work is going on will be difficult.

Comment: Tip: the disabled should be set to false also in case the promise runs into error state, or the button will be disabled forever. That's a perfect case for the yet missing `WinJS.Promise.finally` method :) Then you could just write `WinJS.Promise.timeout(5000).finally(function() { bindingSource.disabled = false; });`